# Checking the type of a polymorphic object

Tags: c#, polymorphism

In C#, if I have a polymorphic object, how can I determine the type of the object, with out checking for the base type?

Here is an example:

```
class object1 : object2
{

}

testObject = new object1();
```

Both the following lines of code return true:

```
bool test1 = testObject is object1;
bool test2 = testObject is object2;
```

How can I do a check so that `test2` returns false?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
bool test2 = testObject.GetType() == typeof(object2);
```

Answer (score 1):

user3736648, you got an answer, how to do that, but unfortunately nobody told you, why your version did not work.

The **is** keyword is trying to answer, whether the instance is of `object2` and there is one, inherited by `object1` so the answer is true on both lines of your test because you can assign like this:

`object2 obj = testObject`;

`obj` would be just missing methods/properties of `object1`,
but the base class, inherited class, `object2` instance is there.

similar for keyword **as**,

```
bool test3 = (testObject as object1) != null;//true
bool test4 = (testObject as object2) != null;//true
```

And finally, why `GetType` works? It is based on reflection and
it does not try to play with inheritance, just result type.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Use is for verifying this

if (obj is MyObject)
{

}

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx

Answer (score -3):

```
 var testObject = new object2();

 bool test1 = testObject is object1;
```

Comment: I didn't fully read the question, but I hate people that just sit back waiting to down vote.

Comment: Downvotes are useful tools to indicate an answer is invalid, and are more frequently awarded depending on the severity of mis/irrelevant information, etc. Sometimes the best solution is to simply use [delete]; possibly followed by posting another (corrected) answer. Such should *not* be taken personally.

Comment: Please add a description of how this solves the users question. Also, please read [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)